# Convert Row to Column

Tags: sql, db2, pivot

How can I convert this table:-

```
INV   DESCRIPTION   AMOUNT
--------------------------
1001  CHARGES       100
1001  FREIGHT       30
1001  INSURANCE     20
1002  CHARGES       215
1002  FREIGHT       32
1002  INSURANCE     25
```

to this format using SQL:-

```
INV   CHARGES  FREIGHT  INSURANCE
---------------------------------
1001  100      30       20
1002  215      32       25
```

Comment: The operation is called pivoting.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pivot/faq

Comment: Serge Rielau recently wrote a blog post about pivoting in DB2: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/pivoting_tables56

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT t.inv,
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.description = 'CHARGES' THEN t.amount ELSE NULL END) AS charges,
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.description = 'FREIGHT' THEN t.amount ELSE NULL END) AS freight,
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.description = 'INSURANCE' THEN t.amount ELSE NULL END) AS insurance
    FROM YOUR_TABLE t
GROUP BY t.inv
ORDER BY t.inv
```

In order to support a dynamic list of descriptions, you'd have to specify which database this is for because the dynamic SQL syntax is different for each one.

PIVOT/UNPIVOT is ANSI syntax, but support is limited:

- SQL Server 2005+
- Oracle 11g+

MySQL doesn't support PIVOT, nor does SQLite.  I don't know when/if PostgreSQL or DB2 does...

Comment: @Bob: Updated, but "it doesn't work" doesn't give me anything to work with.  We don't all have DB2 at our disposal to test with, nevermind the version.