# Convert row into column SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Table  name  is  UserData and  name column is  PRIMARY KEY ,I have a query returning the following
like

> select  name , jobProfile from  UserData
>
> ```
> name  |  jobProfile
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
>   a   |   Admin
>   b   |   user
>   c   |   employee
>   d   |   Admin
>   e   |   user
>   f   |   user
>   g   |   employee
> ```

I would like  to make the results like so  (if  possible)

> ```
>  user  | employee |  Admin
> ___________________________
>  b     |  c       |  a
>  e     |  g       |  d
>  f     |  null    |  null
> ```

Comment: Why are `b`, `c`, and `a` on the same row in the output? That is, what rules govern the transformation?

Comment: @Oded - from what I can see, unique values in `job profile` column define output columns. Values in the columns correspond to `name` column of the input.

Comment: @Alex - yes, I saw that. Still doesn't explain why `f`, `c` and `d` are in different rows, for example.

Comment: @Oded - I assumed it does not matter which value goes to which row, as long as it is in the column it belongs to.

Comment: @Alex - You assume, I don't... I want the OP to tell me, before I give an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Row to Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677287/convert-row-to-column)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand why people trying to close this question. Seems like legit question to me and not exactly a duplicate of referenced question. Referenced question has 3 columns as input, while this question has two. So there is an extra trick needed.

```
-- test data
declare @UserData table (Name varchar(10), JobProfile varchar(10))

insert @UserData
values
  ('a' ,  'Admin'),
  ('b' ,  'user'),
  ('c' ,  'employee'),
  ('d' ,  'Admin'),
  ('e' ,  'user'),
  ('f' ,  'user'),
  ('g' ,  'employee')

-- query
select [user], [employee], [Admin]
from
(
    select *, row_number() over (partition by JobProfile order by Name) RowNumber
    from @UserData
) as p
pivot
(
    min(Name) for JobProfile in ([user], [employee], [Admin])
) as t
order by RowNumber
```

The output:

```
user       employee   Admin
---------- ---------- ----------
b          c          a
e          g          d
f          NULL       NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide very much information, or any rules that govern the transformation, the only answer I can give is check out the **PIVOT** function.