# How can transpose the output of an SQL query?

Tags: sql, db2, transpose

I have a select query in db2 as follows: 
select * from question where app_id=123 and person_id=001

result:

```
question answer app_id   person_id
q1.1       1    123      001
q1.2       1    123      001
q1.3       2    123      001
q1.4       3    123      001
q1.5       3    123      001
```

My requirement is the query output should be displayed 
and write to csv file too.

```
app_id person_id   q1.1    q1.2  q1.3  q1.4  q1.5
123    001          1        1     2    3      3
```

I need help..everyone can design sql query statement.

Answer (score 0):

DB2 doesn't have a built-in [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function like SQL Server, but you should be able to take a look at [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529107/pivoting-in-db2) other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677287/convert-row-to-column/) on how you can simulate the functionality in DB2.