# SQL Grouping and counting together

Tags: sql, db2, db2-9.7

I try to get the grouping elements as column and the count as row elements.

Possible Status = IO, NIO, OPEN, CLOSED, CANCELLED
Possible Types = TypeA, TypeB, typeC, typeD

```
MyTable (date, status, type, count)

2014-06-27,OPEN,typeA, 1
2014-07-01,OPEN,typeA, 1
2014-07-02,IO,typeB, 2
2014-07-02,IO,typeC, 3
2014-07-02,NIO,typeC, 4
```

The result should look like. (Groupping on date and status)

```
date,status,typeA_Count, typeB_Count, typeC_Count, typeD_Count

2014-06-27,OPEN,1, 0, 0, 0
2014-07-01,OPEN,1, 0, 0, 0
2014-07-02,IO, 0, 2, 3, 0
2014-07-02,NIO, 0, 0, 4, 0
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: What flavour of SQL are you using?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen I use Db2 DB...

Comment: @LukeH I use DB2 database

Comment: `DB2 database`? Which one? That is, how old or new is it? (What release?) And what platform is it installed on? (Different platforms have their own special capabilities or restrictions.)

Comment: This is a bog-standard [Pivot Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677287/convert-row-to-column).  Beyond that, you should _really_ avoid using reserved words (like `date`, or `count`) for identifiers.  For one thing, in the case of `date`, it doesn't really even mean anything.  Date of what?  Creation of the row, modified, your mother's birthday?  Be more specific, so future maintainers (like yourself) will thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way is using `CASE/GROUP BY` to add up the values;

```sql
SELECT "date", "status",
  SUM(CASE WHEN "type"='typeA' THEN "count" ELSE 0 END) typeA_count,
  SUM(CASE WHEN "type"='typeB' THEN "count" ELSE 0 END) typeB_count,
  SUM(CASE WHEN "type"='typeC' THEN "count" ELSE 0 END) typeC_count,
  SUM(CASE WHEN "type"='typeD' THEN "count" ELSE 0 END) typeD_count
FROM mytable
GROUP BY "date", "status"
ORDER BY "date", "status"
```

[An Oracle SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f6bd8/1), although DB2 should run the same without problems.

Answer (score 0):

DB2 doesn't support the PIVOT clause therefore try this:

```
select date
     , status
     , sum(decode(type,'typeA',count,0)) as count_typeA
     , sum(decode(type,'typeB',count,0)) as count_typeB
     , sum(decode(type,'typeC',count,0)) as count_typeC
     , sum(decode(type,'typeD',count,0)) as count_typeD
  from mytable
 group by date, status
```